# How to test jackson-jaxrs-json-provider (Arquillian + Wildfly)

Tags: json, jackson, jax-rs, wildfly-8, jboss-arquillian

I'm using Jackson JSON provider in order to serialize/deserialize JAXRS requests.

In order to set it up I've a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file under `WEB-INF` folder:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" services="import"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

So, I've built a test in order to get it:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class FollowUpActivityDTOSerializationTest
{

    @Inject private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment()
    {   
        System.getProperties().remove("javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory");
        EmbeddedGradleImporter importer = ShrinkWrap.create(EmbeddedGradleImporter.class);
        WebArchive war = importer.forThisProjectDirectory().importBuildOutput().as(WebArchive.class);

        war.addClass(ArquillianAlternative.class);
        war.addClass(MockFactory.class);
        war.addAsWebInfResource(
            new StringAsset("<alternatives><stereotype>com.living.mock.ArquillianAlternative</stereotype></alternatives>"),
            "beans.xml"
        );

        JavaArchive[] libs = Maven.resolver().resolve("org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.31-beta").withTransitivity().as(JavaArchive.class);
        war.addAsLibraries(libs);

        return war;
    }

    @Test
    public void emptyJSON()
    {   
        String emptyJSON = "{\"id\": \"id\"}";

        try {
            FollowUpActivityDTO dto = this.mapper.readValue(emptyJSON, FollowUpActivityDTO.class);
            assertNotNull(dto);
            assertEquals(dto.getId(), "id");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            fail(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is Weld tells me that:

> Unsatisfied dependencies for type ObjectMapper with qualifiers @Default

The question, how can I get the jackson provider?

Comment: I can't tell if the jackson jars are actually in the war, please add that output as well.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing here is to get in testing time, the same `ObjectMapper` that JAX-RS implementation would use.

It's important because I configure some settings related to this object in my provider:

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonConfig implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(final Class<?> type) {

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);

        return mapper;
    }

}
```

So, it's important to use this `provider`.

So, in order to inject this object I've written this injection code:

```
@Inject private ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> mapperResolver;
```

Answer (score -1):

By default, there is no producer for `ObjectMapper` unless you explicitly provided one.  If you replace your injection point with an instantiation of the `ObjectMapper`, e.g. `private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()` you'll avoid the injection problem.